# Mocha Not Picking Up Tests in Sub-Folder

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am setting up some tests in my Node project using Mocha with Chai. I have numerous tests running successfully, and now I'd like to group them a little more logically. Right now all tests are located in one "test" folder, which is at the root of the project.

I'm noticing that when I create a sub folder within that "test" folder, and put a test in there, that it never gets run by Mocha. Any idea why this is happening? My understanding is that Mocha runs tests within any folder named "test", as well as any sub-directories *within* that "test" folder.

My package.json look like this:

```
{
  "name": "event_runner",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha || true",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "agenda": "^2.1.0",
    "agendash": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mariadb": "^2.1.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-datetime": "^1.5.0",
    "mocha": "^6.2.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get tests to run I was just typing `mocha` from the command line. This works ONLY when all tests are in one root folder. I did find a solution to run all tests, including those in sub-folders. On my mac I have to run this from the command line:

```
mocha "./test/" --recursive
```

BONUS: To exit after running tests, add the `--exit` flag:

`mocha "./test/" --recursive --exit`

Comment: My 'test' folder under 'src' folder and this works for me: mocha './src/test/' --recursive --exit